# AngularJS and Jquery: angular dosen't bind on jquery navigation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile, ng-bind

Jquery  is ignoring all Angular ng binds(ng-app,ng-controller,ng-bind..) on page change.They are working in index but when I navigate to other pages ng-s just aren't working.Is there a way to "rebind" angular when page dynamically changes?

in first html:

```
<section data-role="page" ng-app="aki" ng-controller="akicontroller">

<a href="sec.html"></a>

</section>
```

in second html ng-app and ng-controller are ignored:

```
<section data-role="page" ng-app="aki" ng-controller="akicontroller">

</section>
```

Pages are loaded via jquery in dom.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem you're seeking help for seems a little unclear... can you set up an example?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` is used for designating the root of the app and should be placed in root elements of the page (html/body). If you do actually need >2 apps running in one html document then you must bootstrap them. Refer to the Angular documentation for ng-app: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Comment: even if ng-app is in html tag in index,on page change that bind isnt't working

Comment: Are you including all the necessary .js files in your sec.html page?  It's a whole new page, so you'll need to load up angular.js again.

Comment: Yes,i am including them.It isn't whole new page it is just section loaded from another html and inserted in dom.Angular just dosent't proccess it.

Comment: I just need to refire angular to "see" ng in dynamically loaded html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use jquery with angular, you should convert any plugin into a directive. The video below explains alot on how it is done.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Bu73oQQSio

This will ensure that your bindings update.

Comment: please post a demo or plunkr